# Make reproducible assertions about query count in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

If I use the pooled SequenceGenerator

```
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_seq")
 @SequenceGenerator(name = "my_seq", sequenceName = "my_seq", allocationSize = 10)
```

then my query assertions (make asserts about number of SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT statements) fail sometimes due to the pooling, the statement(s)

```
select nextval ('my_seq')
```

are sometimes called before and sometimes during the test.

Is there a way to "reset" the pool behind the SequenceGenerator for each test (I don't want to use DirtiesContext, because it slows down the tests)